# JTextArea is repositioning and reziseing itself

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

i just started to use Java to build a GUI. Now i ran in an error that causes very strange behaviour with the JTextArea. I used this to create the TextArea: 
`

```
public class gui{
    JTextArea ausgabe;
    public gui(){
     //Some other Stuff in here
     //
     //
     ausgabe = new JTextArea("Test \n Text",15,50);
     ausgabe.setSize(110, 170);
     ausgabe.setVisible(true);
     mainFrame.add(ausgabe);
     ausgabe.setLocation(170,20);
     ausgabe.setEnabled(false);
    }
 }
```

Now until this point everything just works fine. But I want another method to change the text of the area (with `ausgabe.setText("String");`) the area relocates itself to x,y = 0 of the JFrame and layers itself above all other JFrame elements. Thanks for help!

Comment: Swing uses layout managers. The layout manager is responsible for determining the size and location of the component. You should NOT be trying to set that manually. The 15, 50, is used by the text area to determine its preferred size. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. Also, Swing components are visible by default so there is no need to make the text area visible.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend not trying to fight the [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

For a simple fix, use the default layout manager for a `JFrame` like so

```
public class gui
{
    JTextArea ausgabe;

    public gui()
    { 
        ausgabe = new JTextArea("Test \n Text");
        mainFrame.add(ausgabe, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
 }
```

You also don't need to set Swing Components other than the JFrame itself visible.

You can then call `setText()` in an action listener or such and the `TextArea` should stay in the same position.